# Use amazon iOS sdk v2 from CocoaPod with parse sdk framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, parse-platform, cocoapods

I have our images upload on on s3 and for that i have use amazon iOS sdk v2 with no problem (install sdk via pod).

Now I want to try out some push notification which i came across [Parse](https://parse.com) 
however, i cannot make use of their sdk because they also require bolt framework to run which is already come with amazon sdk from pod.

this is the error

[image]

the location of the error file

[image]

the link framework, I added parse library

[image]

Here is my Pod spec. and pod library

[image]
[image]

I don't know how can I make this work.
Any way I can ignore install Bolt that come with amazon sdks in pod file

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your Podfile and the errors you're seeing?

Comment: I added more information, thanks.

Comment: Can you post your Podfile please?